# как в обработчике событий указать клик на определенную клавишу?

Tags: java, javafx, события

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как указать в обработчике клик именно по определенной клавише:

1. левая кнопка мыши в `onMouseClicked`;
2. зажатая клавиша <kbd>ctrl</kbd> в `onKeyPressed`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ( mouseEvent.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY ) {/**/}
if ( keyEvent.isControlDown() ){/**/}
```